# Firebase retrieving multiple strings from a database

Tags: java, arrays, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to retrieve multiple strings from my database contained in one line 
is this possible to do? 
[Array of strings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GEzf8.png)

And this is what my database looks like when it's in the [Firebase Database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SBpjh.png)

As you can see the database only contains Gas station is there a way for me to retrieve the string manager or mechanic?

Comment: I think you can retrieve everything in one line (in android dataSnapshot.getvalue()). It comes in curly brace enclosed

Comment: im sorry can u give me an example of what u mean

Comment: You question is incomplete. Add youe entire database structure and some code.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified any platform. In android you get data like this

```
final DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(<ROOT_TAG>);
ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String data = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
    });
}
```

Comment: ive tried that but it only gets the gas station part of the string, im trying to store the other parts like manager or mechanic into another variable

Comment: Have you used the correct root tag? If you do, you will get everything